# How to get the Total Amount Each Customer Has Spent

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am making a database for a simple purchase, customer, employee, etc tables.

I am making a query that includes all of the employees who have boughten something, along with some of their data, and then the last field is supposed to have the total amount that they have boughten. However, I am not too sure on how to achieve this.

I am not quite sure on how to get the total to be almost like a sub-query to total up what the customer has gotten. For instance, the first 5 rows should have a total of 180.40.

I have been looking online for some help with totaling queries but couldn't find any good examples.

Any help would be wonderful! Thank you (I am pretty new to SQL and Access)!

Edit: Forgot to add this!

```
SELECT Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Purchase.PurchaseID, Product.ProductName, Product.Price, Product.Price AS Total
FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN (Customer INNER JOIN (Product INNER JOIN Purchase ON Product.ProductID = Purchase.ProductID) 
ON Customer.CustomerID = Purchase.CustomerID) ON Employee.EmployeeID = Customer.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Please show us your existing query.

Comment: Sorry! Edited it!

Comment: Thanks. But you still miss the `select` clause of the query.

Comment: Alright, again very sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking about how to generate a running total or a group summary. The first would add the current line to the total of the lines before it, as in buying the first item for $10, which would give a total of $10, and then buying a second item for $10 would give you a total of $20 ($10 for the first plus $10 for the second). A group summary would add all the lines for that employee and give you a single line containing the total (a line for item 1 @ $10, a line for item 2 @ $10, and then a third line for the total of $20).

Comment: I believe the second one. So, in this case, the first 5 lines are the same customers and in the total column, it would have 180.40. The next 5 lines again would have  be the total for that customer. No need to have a running total.

Comment: Rather than attempting to explain in a comment, instead [edit] your question and make it clear what you're asking there so it can be seen. It would help if you would show an example of the output you're wanting to get, too. FWIW, I find what you've explained to be confusing to users - if line 1 shows a purchase of 1 item @ $10 with a total column showing $25, and a line 2 with another purchase of 1 item @10 with a total of $25 and a line 3 with 1 item @ $5 with a total of $25, I'd be scratching my head trying to figure out why you did it that way. :-)

Comment: I guess my explanation wasn't clear, however, I did include that an example of the first five lines. As for why someone might want this, possibly a total amount on their account still owed, or this query could get passed into another processing stage.

Comment: I think you're sql is not getting the results you are requesting.  You will need to post your table structure if you want a good answer.  You should use SUM() and Group By to get your desired totals but that depends on how your tables are structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName,   
       SUM(p.Price)
FROM ((Employee as e INNER JOIN 
       Customer as c
       ON e.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID 
      ) INNER JOIN 
      Purchase pu
      ON c.CustomerID = pu.CustomerID
     ) INNER JOIN
     Product as p 
     ON p.ProductID = pu.ProductID
GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName;
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! It was just the totaling for the employee/customer which I was having so many issues with! Thank you so much!!